# Curl Perl module not working, formadd method missing

Tags: perl, http, forms, curl

I want to use following script:

```
use FileHandle;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
use WWW::Curl::Form;

my $file, my $curl, my $curlf, my $return, my $minified;

$file = new FileHandle();

$curl = new WWW::Curl::Easy();
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, "http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile");
$curlf = new WWW::Curl::Form();
$curlf->formadd('output_format',      'text');
$curlf->formadd('output_info',        'compiled_code');
$curlf->formadd('compilation_level',  'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS');
$curlf->formaddfile($name, 'js_code', 'multipart/form-data');
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, $curlf);

$file->open(\$minified, ">");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, $file);
$return = $curl->perform();
```

Following error is thrown:

```
Can't locate object method "formadd" via package "WWW::Curl::Form" at ./minifyjs.pl ....
```

WHY??? The WWW::Curl module is installed properly, I used package libwww-curl-perl under Debian/Ubuntu.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: *->new instead of new * doesn't work, too.

Answer (score 4):

Whoops.

Looks like [this commit](http://github.com/szbalint/WWW--Curl/commit/7a0c6559a20f83a9420e83c51d7378d4ff302544) broke formadd. The XS sub doesn't match the `PREFIX = curl_form_` declaration (as it's named `curl_formadd`), so perl doesn't know how to map the Perl version of the method back to XS.

4.12 was the first release that tried to support `WWW::Curl::Form`, looks like it didn't work after all. Not sure how I've missed this one. I should probably note it here that  `WWW::Curl::Form` support wasn't exactly a high priority TODO item on my list, due to the existence of various high quality form handling modules on CPAN. I've only accepted the patch for the sake of feature completeness. You're encouraged to use those modules for managing form content. The standard WWW::Curl [use case statement](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.12/lib/WWW/Curl.pm#USAGE_CASES) applies.

I released 4.13 to fix this issue. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epetdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.64/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm). It has a lot of nice form methods.